# Get Frisby.js tests to run synchronously

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-node, frisby.js

I have these API calls in my test that need to run first so I can store the response in a variable to use later. But it looks like my tests are running asynchronously so the second test finishes before the variable gets populated. How can I make the tests run synchronously?

I've heard that one way is to use `before` and passing the `done` callback. But I'm not sure how to do that with `jasmine-node`.

Example of test:

```
var dataID = '';
frisby.create('Get ID')
  .get(url)
  .expectStatus(200)
  .afterJSON(function(json) {
     dataID = json.id;
  })
.toss();

frisby.create('Get data with ID')
  .get(url, id)
  .expectStatus(200)
  .expectJSON({"id": dataID})
.toss();
```

EDIT:

So I tried doing my test like this and the `done()` callback doesn't seem to get called. (The test times out)

```
describe('API TEST', function() {
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    frisby.create('Get ID')
      .get(url)
      .expectStatus(200)
      .afterJSON(function(json) {
        dataID = json.id;
        done();  //?
      })
      .toss()
  });
  it('should work', function() {
    console.log('TEST');
  }); //"timed out after 5000 msec waiting for spec to complete"
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using the `async` library and doing `.timeout(60000)` on the actual frisby test like so:

```
async.series([
  function(cb) {
    frisby.create('Get ID')
      .get(url)
      .expectStatus(200)
      .afterJSON(function(json) {
        dataID = json.id;
        cb();
      })
      .toss();
  },
  function() {
     //other tests using id
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. That is odd it has to be done that way but maybe the test just takes longer than the default timeout for done on frisbyjs. In any case, glad you found a working solution.

Comment: You might try the `done` approach again after increasing the default timeout -- see this issue for how: https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues/80

Answer (score 3):

Jasmine handles asynchronous tests by passing a special `done` parameter to the test function as an argument -- you have to call done (ie `done()`) when the asynchronous part finishes.

Here is an example test using done:

```
describe('my test', function() {
  it('completes on done', function(done) {
    var a = 10;

    // this would normally be a call to the code under test
    setTimeout(function() {
      a = 20;
    }, 250);

    setTimeout(function() {
      expect(a).toEqual(20);
      done();
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

In the case of frisby.js, it appears that asynchronous testing is surprisingly still an issue. See the issues on the github repo:

[open frisby issues involving async](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20%20async)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late but in case someone else might have the same question.
You can nest the second test into the `afterJson()` of the first test like this to make sure it runs after the first one is done

```
frisby.create('Get ID')
  .get(url)
  .expectStatus(200)
  .afterJSON(function(json) {
     var dataID = json.id;
     frisby.create('Get data with ID')
        .get(url, id)
        .expectStatus(200)
        .expectJSON({"id": dataID})
    .toss()
  })
.toss();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did smaller modification for me in this function but this works for adding node with escape character in xml

```
private void somefunctToReplaceTxtinExistingNode(Node tempNode, String texttobeSet){
    String newtext = "<" + tempNode.getNodeName() + ">" + texttobeSet + "</" + tempNode.getNodeName() + ">";
    // create of new temp document .node will be imported from this
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = ....
    DocumentBuilder builder = ..
    Document newDoc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(texttobeSet));

    Node nodeXmlWithEscapeChars = newDoc.getFirstChild();
    // Import the node in old doc
    Document document = tempNode.getOwnerDocument();
    Node impNode = document.importNode(nodeXmlWithEscapeChars, true);
    // lastly . delete old with 
    Node parent = tempNode.getParentNode();
    parent.removeChild(tempNode);
    parent.appendChild(impNode);
}
```